# Maximum value of accelerometer readings on Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, measurement

I am using androids sensor manager to get accelerometer readings. The readings I am getting are m/s2 and are just about fine. But the maximum reading that I get,on any axis in any direction is |19.xx| , which is approximately 2 Gs. Is this a smartphone specific issue or is there some setting that I need to change to get greater values?

this is the code that I am using to get the sensor for accelerometer:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager
            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (sensors.size() > 0) {
        sensor = sensors.get(0);
        float max = sensor.getMaximumRange();
        boolean running = sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
                sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);           
    }
```

and this is how the onSensorChanged() looks like

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        now = event.timestamp;

        x = event.values[0];
        y = event.values[1];
        z = event.values[2];

    }
```

I am using Android API Level 7.

And I have tested on two phones :
HTC HD 2 (Android 2.3.5)
Samsung Spica (Android 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

"Exact Values" are not there. It will vary by device. Acceleration can be positive or negative - getMaximumRange() , I would assume you can safely multiply that value by -1 to get the minimum value.

Comment: I used getMaximumRange() and it returned 1.0. But the maximum value I get is 19.xx m/s^2. Is this an anomaly..?

Comment: I have the same problem. getMaximumRange() returned 2.0 for me (Samsung Galaxy Ace, 2.3.3, accelerometer) and I can easily get 10.0 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the G's doing this:
Gs = sqrt (Xg^2 + Yg^2 + Zg^2) where ^2 means sqr or square (X^2 = X*X)
That will give you the Gs applied.